# creating a webform block that can be used in Layout Builder

Tags: blocks, webforms, layout-builder

My problem is I've created a webform block type, and I can access it from Layout Builder, but when I place the block on a page in Layout Builder, I'm warned "This block is reusable! Any changes made will be applied globally." And it does. If I drop a form on another page and select a different form, both it and the first page display the same form. How do I make the block such that it can put a unique instance of a form every time I use it and not globally change all block instances to the currently selected form?

Comment: Use a webform reference field on an inline block type.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a module called “Block List Override” on the site I was working on that had a list under “Layout Builder List Regex”. I named my block type following a pattern in that list, added a field for the webform reference, deleted the body field, hid the title of the webform field from the display, and then the block appeared as a choice in Layout Builder when I clicked on “Create Content Block”.

Creating a custom block after creating the block type was unnecessary and it created the issue I was having above where trying to use a custom block in more than one place meant that whatever change I made to one block instance affected all of them.

Essentially, I needed to learn the differences between a block type and a custom block.